Can I use FLARE RAG as a substitute for another open source LLM that is not based on OpenAI?
We are preparing a capstone design for our graduation project, and in that project, we want to implement a RAG chatbot using Langchain, where we want to implement FLARE as an open-source LLM model, but we are having difficulties because the flare library in Langchain is based on OpenAI.
So we are trying to modify all the files in the Langchain module to implement flare as an open-source LLM, which we have been trying for more than two weeks, but it is not working well.
I would like to ask you if it is possible to modify the flare module of Langchain and other connected modules by deleting the openAI part, so that we can implement flare using the KoGPT-Trinity model based on Lama or GPT3, which is what we want. What do you think?
(By the way, the source code of the FLARE paper also shows that the LLM consists of the openAI API).
